# Как понять, что вопрос не имеет объективного ответа?

Tags: обсуждение, причины-закрытия

Недавно наткнулся на вопрос о скорости языков. Автор интересовался, какой из четырёх языков быстрее справится с выполнением одинакового алгоритма.

Пока я писал комментарии со своими предположениями (потому как не мог быть уверен, что несу истину, писал это всё не в ответ), вопрос дико заминусили и потом закрыли, как вопрос, не имеющий объективного ответа.

На мой взгляд в такой области, как программирование, очень сложно буквально сформулировать **вопрос, ответ на который априори будет спорным**. В том числе и здесь.

На вопрос можно дать объективный ответ, не вижу причин для его закрытия. Однако это было сделано. Скорость работы языков и нюансы их трансляции - не вопрос религии. Кто-то может знать точный ответ и он лишился шанса поделиться этим знанием.

То, что большинству нравится предполагать, разводя демагогию в формах для ответов - не является недостатком вопроса. Для уточнений, рассуждений и предположений и существуют комментарии/чат, разве не так?

В случае, если ответ может зависеть от неконтролируемых обстоятельств или конкретной ситуации, ответом будет описание этих ситуаций и последствий их воздействия.

Таким образом, как вообще можно понять, что вопрос не имеет ответа?

[Ссылка на тот самый вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1128189/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%8B).

Answer (score 3):

Да, в общем-то, достаточно этой фразы:

> Допустим, реализован **любой** из алгоритмов обхода.

С такой постановкой вы не сможете дать объективный ответ. Если бы вопрос был про конкретный алгоритм с конкретно заданными параметрами и ограничениями, тогда можно было бы о чём-то говорить.

А так ответ зависит от алгоритма, ограничений, типа компилятора, среды выполнения и т.п.

Ответ на вопрос в текущем виде будет размером с книгу и кучей "если" и допущений. На SO принято более чёткие вопросы задавать.

Comment: Не вижу причин, по которым конкретный выбор алгоритма обхода графа повлияет на результат.

Comment: Способ реализации алгоритма и сам алгоритм никак не влияет на процесс трансляции, поэтому не вижу никаких проблем) Данную строчку добавил в вопрос я. Изначально были даны вообще 3 варианта сложности алгоритма без описания самих алгоритмов, я оставил формулировку "любой алгоритм обхода", из чего ясно, что кроме примитивов, может быть, будут использованы словари и другие простейшие структуры. Для вопроса выполнения программы после компиляции, на мой взгляд, деталей более, чем достаточно.

Comment: @SmellyNS, ну вообще способ реализации влияет, так как разные конструкции могут переводиться по разному в разных языках. Если в итоге получится один и тот же бинарный код, то очевидно разницы не будет в том, какой был исходный язык.

Comment: @Grundy, Да, именно поэтому в вопросе написано жирным, что алгоритмы реализованы одинаково) Цепляясь за мелочи вы упускаете детали. Вопрос поставлен вполне корректно и имеет в себе именно тот смысл, о котором каждый подумал. Зачем искать проблемы там, где их нет?